# Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Assume that $A, B, C$ are arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Prove that if $A \subseteq B$, then $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

Proof: Asume that $A \subseteq B$, then there exists an $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. If $x \in A$,then $x \in A \cup C$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in B \cup C$. Therefore $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Remember the case where you possibly have empty sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Suppose $x \in A \cup C $. Then by definition, we know that $x \in A $ or $x \in C$. By Hypothesis, we are given that $A \subseteq B$, then we must have that $x \in A \implies x \in B$. Hence

$$ x \in A  \; \; or \; \;x \in C \implies x \in B \; \; or \; \; x \in C \implies x \in B \cup C$$

Therefore, we have shown that $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C $ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not quite correct. The idea of element chasing is as follows:

To show that $A\cup C \subseteq B \cup C$: You want to show that any element of $A \cup C$ is also an element of $B \cup C$.

To that end you would say, suppose $x \in A \cup C$.

(You fill in the blank here!)

and conclude that $x \in B \cup C$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x \in A \cup C $.  Then $x\in A$ or $x \in C$.

Case 1.  Assume $x \in C$.  So $x \in B \cup C$.

Case 2.  Assume $x \in A$.  Then because $A \subseteq B$,  $x \in B $.  Thus $x\in B \cup C$.

So if $x \in A \cup C $ and $A \subseteq B$, then $ x \in B \cup C $.